# Best Way to Import Other Modules in Python when PYTHONPATH Cannot Be Modified?

Tags: python, module, directory, project, import

I'm coding my first project in python, and I'm unsure as to how to handle importing.  I'm working on computers at my university and cannot modify the PYTHONPATH variable.  I am also working on this project from a variety of computers/OSs (so the path to the project is not always the same).

I have a number of different modules in different folders which all import eachother.  Currently I get the path to one module from another by using `file_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)` and then backtracking through the directories and then appending the folder with the desired module in it.  This is then added to the PYTHONPATH with `sys.path.append(symantic_root)`.

This system works, but it ends up looking very messy and there is a lot of duplicated code at the beginning of each module, for example:

```
import os
import sys
# Get the path to the directory above the directory this file is in, for any system
file_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
root_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(file_path))
# Get the paths to the directories the required modules are in
symantic_root = os.path.join(root_path, "semantic_analysis")
parser_root = os.path.join(root_path, "parser")
# Add the directories to the path variable
sys.path.append(symantic_root)
sys.path.append(parser_root)
import semantic_analyser
import jaml
```

Any advice on a better way to structure a project such as this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a simple `main.py` script which provides a single point of entry for your application. For example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys   
    from package import app

    sys.exit(app.run())
```

Next, create a top-level package that groups together all your modules, and provide an access point for it *in the same directory* as `main.py`. You should then be able to eliminate all the path manipulation code, and simply use fully specified import statements like `from package.module import function` from any module within your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm just wandering what you mean exactly when you say "provide access points".  Is this something to do with the __init__.py file?

Comment: @Alty. You didn't make it clear in your question to what extent you can restructure the folders your modules are currently in, and I wasn't sure what os you were using - so "access point" just means a plain directory, or a symbolic link, etc. The key thing is finding a way to bring all your modules together under a single package - then things become much simpler to manage (hope I'm not just stating the obvious here).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should read some of the stuff about Python paths in the following documents:

- http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path
- http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/site/index.html

To solve your problem you could probably use a pth ([python-search-path](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path)) file containing list of paths your required modules exist in.

Then from your main script you could do

```
import site
site.addsitedir(".")
```

which will automatically append those directories to `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what OS you're working on.  Much of this answer presupposes a Linux (or Unix-like) environment.  If you're on Windows, someone else will have to chime in.

It's not clear from your example why you're going through all of these contortions. First, how are you unable to modify `PYTHONPATH`?  This is just a shell environment variable.  If you can log in and run Python, you demonstrably have the necessary access to set your own environment variables.

But I'm not even sure that's necessary.  If you were to simply install all of your custom modules into your own library directory, and install `.pth` files as suggested by vinilios, you could just do something like this:

```
import site
import os

site.addsitedir(os.path.expanduser('~/lib/python'))
```

You may also want to take a look into the [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) package, which lets you create your own Python environment into which you can install your own packages.  It's very handy when you need to install modules that aren't available in the system Python.